# Ruby on Rails Directory Permissions Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, rbenv

I am trying to install bundler and I get the following error.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I have poked around on this site and other places and found the common suggestion to install rbenv, which I did using homebrew. I also added Add rbenv init to my shell using the following command:

```
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I then started a new shell so that PATH changes take effect then checked if rbenv was set up:

```
$ type rbenv
#=> "rbenv is a function"
```

All good so far.

Then I try to install bundler again using the `gem install bundler` and I still get the error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I have also been experiencing problems with my Python setup and I suspect this is symptomatic of the same root cause, but I'm not sure what to do next. Any ideas?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.1

Comment: I should also mention its rbenv version 0.4.0, and ruby 2.0.0p247, the PATH is (looks like a diaster) /Users/mervmerzoug/.rbenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin

Answer (score -1):

Try making your directory permissions less restrictive with `chmod` or Finder > File > Get Info. Also, check that your `umask` isn't more restrictive than you want.

Comment: OP should be able to install local gems instead of system-wide ones. See  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23510249/1899424

Answer (score -1):

Definitely avoid changing permissions, especially since rbenv is possibly using the system's ruby. Instead you should have your own ruby, locally, with rbenv. Somewhere rbenv is still using the root owned system's version instead of your local PATH.

> OP should be able to install local gems instead of system-wide ones.
>
> See stackoverflow.com/a/23510249/1899424 – dcorking Feb 29 at 10:52

This helped put me in the right direction resolving the same issue you've encountered. Still trying to get snorby.